# A name of a design approach?

Tags: interface-design

There is this new UI design thing going on for a while, where the UI is made with wide variety of strong/retro colour palette, its a **vector design** ,and the whole design is "digital" and over simplified = *no shadows, no details, pretty bold but very intelligent* .

You can see it in many places and I am  trying to read more about this approach but I don't know its name ?

Examples :

- google's general design approach,the simplicity and colours
- or these guys  https://ifttt.com

Comment: Look at this question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37531/what-are-the-basic-rules-of-flat-design and also http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/what-is-the-difference-between-flat-style-and-material-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flat Design**

for what google recently announced, thats **material design** & **flat ui design**

for that quirly line style, look at **flat line art**